# how does opencart calulate total amounts?

Tags: php, opencart

I have two price fields in the products table in the database of an opencart site. The display of which price is determined by the type of user thats logged in.

Throughout the site I have all the correct prices being displayed based on which user, but I just cant figure out how the total price is calculated.

This is from my confirm.php

```
        $total_data = array();
        $total = 0;
        $taxes = $this->cart->getTaxes();

        $this->load->model('setting/extension');

        $sort_order = array(); 

        $results = $this->model_setting_extension->getExtensions('total');

        foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
            $sort_order[$key] = $this->config->get($value['code'] . '_sort_order');
        }

        array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $results);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            if ($this->config->get($result['code'] . '_status')) {
                $this->load->model('total/' . $result['code']);

                $this->{'model_total_' . $result['code']}->getTotal($total_data, $total, $taxes); 

            }
        }
```

I have successfully edited the taxes from system/library/cart.php , I have tried looking in total folder at the code, but I just dont know where its getting the price from. I have tried `getTotal` in cart.php also, but no luck.

Thank you

Comment: Please, **without offence**, consider deleting this question - mostly because the very low quality answer You have given Yourself - as it brings no value for the community. Or, **in better way**, extend Your own answer for this question and describe, how the total amounts are really calculated, so that in the future this question with Your own findings may help somebody else.

Comment: Ill delete it actually, you're right, it is far too complex a question and answer where my own problem was only one small part of it.

Comment: @Adrian have you come up with any solution i am having the same problem.